# How to access a MongoDB Database through a name "mongodb://127.0.0.1/testDatabase"

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

i would like to know how to set up a mongoDB Database so i can access it with a name such as "mongodb://127.0.0.1/testDatabase".

Havent found anything, due to the fact that i dont know the topic it belogns to.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more detail? How and from where you are trying access to MongoDB?

Comment: Do you want to set up a new mongodb database and connect to it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  Connect to Mongodb Instance:
  In the following example, the URI connection string specifies connecting to a 
  MongoDB instance that is running on localhost using port 27017. 
  The myproject indicates the database to use. 
  If the database is omitted, the MongoClient uses the default test database:


  var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
  , assert = require('assert');

 // Connection URL
 var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject';

// Use connect method to connect to the server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
assert.equal(null, err);
console.log("Connected successfully to server");

db.close();
});
```